# Typescript check if object is iterable

Tags: typescript

I have a class where I want to have a method to add one or more objects to a private collection. The way I want to do this is with overloads and implementation so that callers can use the same method for adding one object as for a collection of objects. I currently have it working like this:

```
import { InterfaceType } from "some/data-model/directory";

export class MyClass {
    private _collection: Array<InterfaceType>;

    constructor() {
        this._collection = [];
    }

    /**
     * Adds a new InterfaceType to the stored InterfaceTypes.
     * @param it The new InterfaceType to be stored.
     */
    public push(it: InterfaceType): void;

    /**
     * Adds new InterfaceTypes to the stored InterfaceTypes.
     * @param its The collection of new InterfaceTypes to be stored.
     */
    public push(its: Iterable<InterfaceType>): void;

    public push(i: InterfaceType | Iterable<InterfaceType>): void {
        if (typeof(i[Symbol.iterator]) === "function") {
            this._collection = this._collection.concat(Array.from(i as Iterable<InterfaceType>));
            return;
        }
        this._collection.push(i as InterfaceType);
    }
```

But note the `as` statements. I didn't need to add those when I had it typed as a `InterfaceType | Array<InterfaceType>` because Typescript recognized when I checked `i instanceof Array`, but because `Iterable` is an interface I can't directly check `instanceof`.

So my question is: how do I get Typescript to recognize that I have checked for and handled the case that a parameter is an `Iterable` without resorting to `as`? Is there no way?

Comment: You need to build a type guard: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types

Comment: Well then the question becomes "how would I write that type guard?". Since `Iterable` is a template type I can't return `arg is Iterable`; I have to give it a type. Checking `typeof(arg[Symbol.iterator]) === "function"` doesn't really suffice to tell you that `arg is Iterable<InterfaceType>`. Is there a way to check what type the iterator function will return?

Answer (score 2):

You need to build a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), as [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60657023/typescript-check-if-object-is-iterable/72409280#comment107316801_60657023) by Roberto Zvjerković.

The following function is a type guard to differentiate `i` from `InterfaceType` and `Iterable<InterfaceType>`.

```js
const isInterfaceTypeIterable = (i: InterfaceType | Iterable<InterfaceType>): i is Iterable<InterfaceType> => {
  return Symbol.iterator in (i as Iterable<InterfaceType>);
};
```

Using it in your code:

```js
import { InterfaceType } from "some/data-model/directory";

export class MyClass {
    private _collection: Array<InterfaceType>;

    constructor() {
        this._collection = [];
    }

    public push(it: InterfaceType): void;
    public push(its: Iterable<InterfaceType>): void;
    public push(i: InterfaceType | Iterable<InterfaceType>): void {
        // using the type guard
        if (isInterfaceTypeIterable(i)) {
            // no longer need casting i to Iterable<InterfaceType>
            this._collection = this._collection.concat(Array.from(i));
            return;
        }
        // no longer need casting i to InterfaceType
        this._collection.push(i);
    }
}
```