# type must have Symbol.iterator method that returns an iterator

Tags: typescript

My code below generates an error saying `Type 'T | Iterable<T>' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator`. Since I have a check right before the point where the error occurs, I expected to see no error. What else does it need?

```
function* concat<T extends object>(...args: (Iterable<T> | T | null | undefined)[]) {
    for (const xs of args) {
        if (xs) {
            if (typeof xs[Symbol.iterator] === 'function') {
                for (const x of xs) { // The use of `xs` variable here generates the error.
                    yield x;
                }
            } else {
                yield xs;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot iterate over records (your `object`) using `of`. Tho you can use `in` to iterate over the keys of said object.

What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: @Murolem clearly it's possible to use `of` since the object exposes an iterator.

Comment: @VLAZ my bad, you right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) in a separate function as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72409280/15076557).

```
function* concat<T extends object>(...args: (Iterable<T> | T | null | undefined)[]) {
    for (const xs of args) {
        if (xs) {
            if (isIterable(xs)) {
                for (const x of xs) { // no error
                    yield x;
                }
            } else {
                yield xs;
            }
        }
    }
}

function isIterable(value: unknown): value is Iterable<unknown> {
    return (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null)
        ? typeof value[Symbol.iterator] === 'function'
        : false;
};
```